# revert to a commit that does not belong to any branch

Tags: git, git-push, git-revert

I accidently force pushed my repo, so I lost some of my commits which become  not belonging to any branch

[image]

I tried :

```
git revert --no-commit <commit>..HEAD
```

or even

```
git reset <commit> --hard
```

but it doesn't work:

```
fatal: bad revision
```

is there a way to revert this commit ?

Comment: Do you see this commit? Maybe `git reflog` can help to revert changes.

Comment: @CoolMind how is that?

Comment: I don't know how to use this command (I tried one day, but haven't succeded). It shows a history of actions and can revert changes.

Comment: You can undo almost any Git mistake with the reflog, as @CoolMind suggested, even after pushing. This might help: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/9c3ea5a6f6-undo-any-git-action-

Comment: A nice sample! Don't repeat it at home (joke). Create another project in Git, do some actions and try to reproduce @JakeWorth code, then repeat the same in working project.

Answer (score 1):

This command:

> ```
> git reset <commit>--hard
> ```

is the closest one to correct, but it contains at least one mistake: the `--hard` is physically joined up against the commit hash, so that the hash looks like `a1234567--hard`, which is not a valid hash ID.

You might have actually run:

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

or:

```
git reset <commit> --hard
```

(which puts the option, `--hard`, on the "wrong side" of the non-option argument, but Git tolerates this<sup>1</sup>).  If that still did not and does not work—with Git *still* complaining that it does not recognize the hash ID as a valid commit (`fatal: bad revision`)—that would indicate that *your* Git repository lacks this commit.  That would be unsurprising because the image you included says:

> ⚠️ This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside the repository.

This particular message is peculiar to those hosting systems that provide "forks" (GitHub and Bitbucket included): the slightly (or heavily) hacked Git implementations on these web hosting sites sneakily *share* storage across multiple forks, so that it's sometimes possible to gain direct access to a commit that's not in *your* fork.<sup>2</sup>  In this case, cloning your own fork might not give you access to that object (see footnote 2 again).  One of Git's new features, though,<sup>3</sup> means that you can access any object by its hash ID once you know it, so you could just `git fetch` the object directly, by its hahs ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git follows a mix of POSIX and GNU option ideas, with its own twists.  Many command-line commands on Unix-like systems follow a stricter POSIX-only model, where dash-prefixed options—whether short ones like `-x` or long ones like `--extended`—must come *before* any additional optional arguments such as file names.  It's a good habit in general to write things like this, so that when you are using, say, the `sed` command, you don't get tripped up by option order.

<sup>2</sup>This has obvious security implications, and if the web hosting site is doing security *properly*, they won't give you access to any commit that you didn't at least *temporarily* have access to, long enough for you to have copied the commit.  They probably should not give you access to the commit if it such access was "revoked", but supporting revocation correctly is hard enough that they might well just not bother, using the excuse that you *had* access to it, and you might have copied at during that time, so now there's no point closing the barn door since the horse was (maybe) cloned.  Low-to-no-cost copying economies are, obviously, fundamentally different from scarcity economies in which if *you* have item X, *nobody else* can have it, and the rules here are still evolving.

<sup>3</sup>This is the new *partial clone* feature.